# javascript goto label how to use inside loop

Tags: javascript

```
for (var rows = 0; rows < 10; rows++) 
{
 [lbl] topOfLoop:   
  if (row  == 5 ) {
    goto topOfLoop;
  }else{ 
alert(row);
   }
```

}

Is there a way to do that in Javascript?

Comment: your example makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `break` to exit a `for` loop, or `continue` to go to the next loop iteration.

javascript has no `goto` statement:

> A Statement may be prefixed by a label. Labelled statements are only used in conjunction with labelled break and continue statements. ECMAScript has no goto statement.

http://es5.github.io/#x12.12

Answer (score 1):

From the MSN documentation for [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

> The **labeled statement** can be used with [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) or [continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) statements. It is prefixing a statement with an identifier which you can refer to.

```js
var i, j;

loop1: for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {       //The first for statement is labeled "loop1"
    loop2: for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {   //The second for statement is labeled "loop2"
        if (i === 1 && j === 1) {
            continue loop1;
        }
        document.write("i = " + i + ", j = " + j + '<br>');
    }
}
```